# In magento, is it possible to update or delete the order items from the order without creating the new order?

Tags: magento

In my case, an order should be modified after the review. Order items can be removed or the quantity can be modified.

I knew the Re order would the do the purpose by manually deleting the old order once re order is completed. But I do not want to change the order id.

Answer (score 0):

In default magento , we cannot edit and delete the order items.

There is one paid extension ( [Edit and delete order item in magento](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/magento-edit-order-manager.html)  ) which give you the facility of:-

1. Editing an order
2. Deleting an order
3. Order quick view
4. Backup orders
5. View product images